# How to separate model popup for next section?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap model to show popup. It is working fine and displaying all the images in the gallery. But now in my page i need another popup and first popup is also showing the next section images in the model. i am using `loadGallery`, in which i am passing two parameters. Second parameter is to identify the click item.

I already tried to calling function twice by using different parameter. i used click function to find which class is called and then pass it to `loadGallery` as second parameter.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    let theClass = $(this).attr('class');
    let modalId = theClass.attr('data-target');
    loadGallery(true, 'a.theClass');    
});
```

I change id for modal  as well . Below is my code with my old scripts.
https://jsfiddle.net/shreya_js/uho4gbm0/15/

I want it will separate into two modals one for row 1 and other for 2 row.

Comment: IDs must be unique. Pay attention to your html source. There are some inconsistencies.

Comment: for first modal id is image-gallery and for second section id is second-gallery. Id is repeated inside the Modal , Actually i want to use one modal , For example-: if i click on first row it will open modal which will show 4 items of first row. But when i click second row, it will display images for next row like a separate popup.   https://jsfiddle.net/shreya_js/uho4gbm0/21/